# Preferred combination SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, linked-data

I am trying to write an elegant SPARQL that gives me one solution for multiple possible queries. I have a number of subjects and a number of predicates and I want to receive a single object. The existence of a single solution is very uncertain so I give multiple options. If I am not mistaken, this can be done with the following query:

```
SELECT ?object
WHERE {
    :subjA|:subjB|:subjC :propA|:propB|:propC ?object.
}
LIMIT 1
```

The real problem is that I do not want any solution. I want order by `:subjA` and then `:propA`. To make it clear; I want the first solution in the following list of combinations:

- `:subjA` `:propA`
- `:subjA` `:propB`
- `:subjA` `:propC`
- `:subjB` `:propA`
- `:subjB` `:propB`
- `:subjB` `:propC`
- `:subjC` `:propA`
- `:subjC` `:propB`
- `:subjC` `:propC`

How to rewrite my query to get the first possible solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for sure not a valid SPARQL query. You can only use `|` for the predicate which will then be called a property path but you're losing the variable binding.

SPARQL returns a set of rows but you can use for example the lexicographical order. Not sure, if this is what you want:

#### sample data

```
@prefix : <http://ex.org/> .

:subjA :propA :o1 .
:subjA :propC :o1 .
:subjB :propB :o1 .
:subjC :propB :o1 .
:subjC :propA :o1 .
:subjA :propC :o2 .
:subjB :propB :o2 .
:subjB :propC :o2 .
```

#### query

```sql
PREFIX : <http://ex.org/>
SELECT  ?s ?p ?o
WHERE
  { VALUES ?s { :subjA :subjB :subjC }
    VALUES ?p { :propA :propB :propC }
    ?s  ?p  ?o
  }
ORDER BY ?s ?p
```

#### result

```
-------------------------
| s      | p      | o   |
=========================
| :subjA | :propA | :o1 |
| :subjA | :propC | :o1 |
| :subjA | :propC | :o2 |
| :subjB | :propB | :o1 |
| :subjB | :propB | :o2 |
| :subjB | :propC | :o2 |
| :subjC | :propA | :o1 |
| :subjC | :propB | :o1 |
-------------------------
```

### Update

Since a used-defined order is wanted, as a workaround an index for entities can be used (I changed the order of `:subjB` and `:subjC` resp. `:propB` and `:propC` to show the difference compared to lexicographical order):

#### query

```sql
PREFIX : <http://ex.org/>
SELECT  ?s ?p ?o
WHERE
  { VALUES (?sid ?s) { (1 :subjA) (2 :subjC) (3 :subjB) }
    VALUES (?pid ?p) { (1 :propA) (2 :propC) (3 :propB) }
    ?s  ?p  ?o
  }
ORDER BY ?sid ?pid
```

#### result

```
-------------------------
| s      | p      | o   |
=========================
| :subjA | :propA | :o1 |
| :subjA | :propC | :o1 |
| :subjA | :propC | :o2 |
| :subjC | :propB | :o1 |
| :subjC | :propA | :o1 |
| :subjB | :propB | :o1 |
| :subjB | :propB | :o2 |
| :subjB | :propC | :o2 |
-------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This solution is elegant, but I do not want to sort alphabetically but manually. Is this possible?

Comment: With a small workaround, yes. See my updated answer.

Comment: This solution seems perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by two ways. They are different by your needs to alphabetic sort or not.
First for alphabetic sort:

```
 Select ?object where {
   {Select (min(?sub) as ?msub) where {
       ?sub :propA|:propB|:propC ?obj1
       Filter ( ?sub = :subjA or :sub=?...)
   } .      
   {Select (min(?prop) as ?mrop_by_msub) where {
       ?msub ?prop ?obj2
       Filter ( ?prop = :propA or ?prop=?...)
   } .
  ?msub ?mrop_by_msub ?object 
}
Limit 1
```

Second way for custom sort:

```
 Select ?object where {
    {:subjA :propA ?object}
    Union
    {:subjA :propB ?object}
    .......
 } limit 1
```

I write all of it by my memory, so there is may be some errors in this code.

Add third way:
You can add to your rdf store something like this:

```
:subjA :order_num 1
:subjB :order_num 2
:subjC :order_num 3
:propA :order_num 1
:propB :order_num 2
:propC :order_num 3
```

And then use query like this:

```
select ?object where{
  ?sub :order_num ?ord_num_sub .
  ?prop :order_num ?ord_num_prop .
  ?sub ?prop ?object
} order by ?ord_num_sub ?ord_num_prop
limit 1
```

or if you want to use different of subjs and props you can add filter:
    filter ( (?ord_num_sub=2 or ?ord_num_sub=3) and (?ord_num_prop=1 or ?ord_num_prop=2) )

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not want an alphabetical sort but a custom sort without any pattern. Is it a given fact that unions are returned in the given order? Still, if it is this will result in a very long query as I want to have 5-10 subjects and 5-10 properties.

Comment: Thank you, but as I cannot edit the dataset, the solution of AKSW is accepted as the best solution.